# Trying to learn React hooks and don't understand why this checkbox behavior is broken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The component loads with 3 todos. If you check the middle one it should get a line through it. Then if you click the [x] button on it, it goes away, but for some reason the todo below it gets checked.

Anyone see the reason for this?

```js
const Todo = props => {
  const markCompleted = (checked, index) => {
    const newTodos = [...props.todos];

    newTodos[index].isCompleted = checked;

    props.setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const deleteTodo = index => {
    const newTodos = [...props.todos];

    newTodos.splice(index, 1);

    props.setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ textDecoration: props.todo.isCompleted ? 'line-through' : '' }}
      className="todo"
    >
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={e => markCompleted(e.target.checked, props.index)}
      />
      {props.todo.text}
      <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(props.index)}>x</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoForm = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const addTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!value) return;

    const newTodos = [...props.todos, { text: value }];

    props.setTodos(newTodos);
    setValue('');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    { text: 'Learn about React', isCompleted: false },
    { text: 'Meet friend for lunch', isCompleted: false },
    { text: 'Build really cool todo app', isCompleted: false }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo, index) => (
          <Todo {...{ key: index, todo, index, todos, setTodos }} />
        ))}
        <TodoForm {...{ todos, setTodos }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
, document.querySelector('#react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previously checked checkbox remains rendered. You should explicitly set its `checked` status instead, so that it's taken from the props every time, rather than possibly from user input:

```
checked={props.todo.isCompleted}
```

You also should use functional methods like `filter` instead of using mutating methods like `splice`, and `newTodos[index].isCompleted = checked;` is mutating the todo object - `[...props.todos]` only shallow clones the array of objects. Spread the todos around the changed object into the array passed to `setTodos` instead.

```
props.setTodos([
  ...todos.slice(0, index),
  { ...todos[index], isCompleted: checked },
  ...todos.slice(index + 1),
]);
```

```js
const Todo = props => {
  const markCompleted = (checked, index) => {
    const { todos } = props;
    props.setTodos([
      ...todos.slice(0, index),
      { ...todos[index], isCompleted: checked },
      ...todos.slice(index + 1),
    ]);
  };

  const deleteTodo = index => {
    props.setTodos(props.todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index));
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{ textDecoration: props.todo.isCompleted ? 'line-through' : '' }}
      className="todo"
    >
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={e => markCompleted(e.target.checked, props.index)}
        checked={props.todo.isCompleted}
      />
      {props.todo.text}
      <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(props.index)}>x</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoForm = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const addTodo = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!value) return;

    const newTodos = [...props.todos, { text: value }];

    props.setTodos(newTodos);
    setValue('');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
    { text: 'Learn about React', isCompleted: false },
    { text: 'Meet friend for lunch', isCompleted: false },
    { text: 'Build really cool todo app', isCompleted: false }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo, index) => (
          <Todo {...{ key: index, todo, index, todos, setTodos }} />
        ))}
        <TodoForm {...{ todos, setTodos }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
, document.querySelector('#react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the tips! Just for posterity, I had to use `checked={!!props.todo.isCompleted}` else was getting the

 > Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa)